# bindValue is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

Using PDO with MariaDB server. I am having trouble understanding why this code does not work. Whenever I have :value for the values it gives me an error " Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (USER, DOMAIN,FLG) VALUES (:username,:domain,:flag)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindValue(':domain', $domain);
    $stmt->bindValue(':flag', $flag);       
    $stmt->execute();
```

But then the code below does work.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (USER, DOMAIN,FLG) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $username);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $domain);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $flag);       
    $stmt->execute();
```

Below is the rest of the section for this code.

```
    if(isset($_POST['addEditor'])){
    $username = $_POST['formUsername'];
    $domain = $_POST['formDomain'];
    $flag = $_POST['formflg'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (USER, DOMAIN,FLG) VALUES (:username,:domain,:flag)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindValue(':domain', $domain);
    $stmt->bindValue(':flag', $flag);       
    $stmt->execute();


  try{                
    $stmt->execute();           
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: Try `bindParam()` instead.

Comment: I tried using bindParam() and was getting the same error

Comment: It's the real code? check this, `if(!$stmt->execute()){print_r($stmt->errorInfo());}`

Comment: give us full fragment of your code. Where this message *Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined* comes from?

Comment: The error is being thrown by the database. I added a bit more of the code. Maybe this will help resolve the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code worked for me have read something about [PDO here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html)

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$username='a';
$domain ='b';
$flag ='c';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`USER`, `DOMAIN`, `FLG`) VALUES (:username,:domain,:flag)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(
  array(':username'=> $username,
    ':domain'=> $domain,
    ':flag'=> $flag)
  );
```

Comment: The code seems right for MySQL but he's using mariaBD maybe something is diferent.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble understanding why this code does not work.

No wonder, as you're using wrong way to understand.

Get rid of *all* `try` and `catch` operators in your code, run it again and then read the *full* error message, that will make you understand *which* code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST)
{
$role ="student";



 try{

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (role)
            VALUES(:qrole)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":qrole", $role);


        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Successfully Added";
        }
        else{
            echo "Query Problem";
        }   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

try this , if some errors occurred it will post it using catch